# "Grep" that highlights instead of filter

Tags: logging, unix, command-line

I was wondering if there is a program in the common unix toolset such as grep that instead of filtering the lines that contain a string, simply outputs the same input but highlighting or coloring the selected string.

I was thinking in doing it by myself (should be simple enough), but maybe it already exists as a unix command.

I'm planning in using it to monitor logs, so I would do something like this:

```
tail -f logfile.log | highlight "error"
```

Usually when I'm monitoring logs I need to find a particular string but I also need to know what is written before and after the string, so filtering sometimes is not enough.

Does something like that exist?

Thanks

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Wops, sorry this was an off-topic question. I'm going to try my luck on software recommendations then.

Comment: @gnat - It is more a programming question than a software recommendation. A better place for this question would be SO or UNIX SE.

Comment: @mouviciel If you are asking how to do it with existing tools, it' a unix question.  If you are asking for a tool to do it, it's a [software recommendation question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14413/450).

Comment: @MichaelT: Both are present in the question: _I was thinking in doing it by myself_ => Unix question; _maybe it already exists as a unix command_ => Software recommendation.

Comment: @mouviciel http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267058/839601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a simple `sed` substitute command with [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) put before and after the matching RE.

```
tail -f logfile.log | sed 's/\(error\)/^[[42m\1^[[0m/g'
```

where `^[` is an ESC character that you can obtain by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-V <kbd>ESC</kbd>

If you do need a `highlight` command, you can define it as a shell function:

```
highlight() { sed 's/'"$1"'\)/^[[42m\1^[[0m/g' ; }
```